# How does optimizer and model work together in tensorflow GAN example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am studying this example in tensorflow website.
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan

My question in the train_step method:

```
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

- What does the **training=True** mean here?  We are just passing in the input tensor and it outputs a tensor.  There is no training involves here.
- How did the generator and discriminator models get trained here?  Seems like the optimiziers are doing the job by calling **apply_gradients**?  But how does it work exactly?  I don't see how optimizers are related to the generator and discriminator models in this code.